# Display Image to UIImageView which comes from Server

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiimageview, nsdata

I am getting strange issue please if get help from anyone then it'll be appreciated.

My problem is i am getting only Image names from server through web service for `ex: abc.png`.

Now that image need to be attached with the static URL & than it will be used to display to `UIImageView`.

I have used this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<[[myDic valueForKey:@"posts"] count]; i++)
{
    NSData *bgImageData = nil;
    if ([[[[myDic valueForKey:@"posts"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"post"] valueForKey:@"video_image"] == [NSNull null])
    {
        bgImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://drupal.org/files/issues/no-pre.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        bgImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sitebildz.com/application/document/video/%@",[[[[myDic valueForKey:@"posts"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"post"] valueForKey:@"video_image"]]]];
    }
    [arrVideoImage addObject:bgImageData];
}
```

For Display in Table :

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[arrVideoImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But don't know why its not working.

Thanks.

Comment: No issue in your code as i think. Please print image name in the loop also length of NSData. n Have you allocated the arrVideoImage array??

Comment: check this library:- https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache

Comment: check the URL, make sure is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing wrong. See you're making `NSData` in loop. Do you think it will wait until image is download from server ??? Nope it will not wait. So in this case you're adding empty `NSData`.

Would be better to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). 
 1. Download it
 2. Import it in your project 
 3. build project (success)
 4. Import `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"` in your `ViewController` class

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImageName"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented The Tiger, your best choice would be to use an external library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which can handle download, caching and display of online images.
Here is an example using this framework :

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

You can also use blocks to insert logic once an image finished loading :

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {... completion code here ...}];
```

Answer (score 1):

you cab use https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/tree/master/EGOImageView which will download the image from server in async way and display once it completely downloaded from server. It also cache that image so that multiple request can be avoided and it enhances the system.